# Display Images Using Route in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to display image using route in Laravel blade. So I am passing route in image src but it is not working.

http://localhost:8000/get-profile-image/id'

Route::get("/get-profile-image/{crewId}", "LandingPagesController@getCrewProfileImage");

Above route will return image path.

This is controller function

```
public function getCrewProfileImage($crewID)
    {
        $res=$this->crewProfileShareRepository->getCrewDetails($crewID);
        echo $res->profile_pic;
    }
```

In blade

```
<img src="{{ url('get-image-path/'.$crewId) }}" />
```

Comment: show your controller for getting profile image path

Comment: controller function added in question. Please check.

Comment: Provide more code of the blade.

Comment: blade code added

Comment: And how do you store the images?

Comment: I am uploading images in public under uploads directory .

Comment: The correct way is to pass the image file name which is retrieved from database  to your blade. after that, reference the image in img tag in this way: `<img src="{{ asset(' uploads/'.$img_name)}}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss single command, `php artisan storage:link`

It will make a symlink to `public` directory and you can directly access it from browser. Also you should using return instead of echo, since *function is returning value, not echo-ing value*.

```php
public function getCrewProfileImage($crewID)
{
   $res=$this->crewProfileShareRepository->getCrewDetails($crewID);
   return $res->profile_pic;
   // or using public_path()
   // return public_path($res->profile_pic);
}
```